# Performance of Looker Studio's Query in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have prepared a sample data of around 1.8GB in three seperate tables. I have then created a materialized view (which contains 7M records) to join the data of these 3 tables.

Using this materialized view, I have created a report in Looker Studio. The report without caching, initially takes around **18-20 seconds** to load data. To create a worst case scenario, I have added a table in the report to show all the dimensions/columns present in the data.

The query job that Looker studio issues to prepare table is as follows:

SELECT t0.address, t0.agent_name, t0.amount, t0.customer_gender, t0.customer_id, t0.customer_name, t0.food_item, t0.phone_number, DATETIME_TRUNC(SAFE_CAST(t0.date AS DATETIME), SECOND) AS t0_qt_gjznucnwed, t0.rating, t0.zipCode FROM `project_id.my_dataset.data_mat_view` AS t0 GROUP BY t0.address, t0.agent_name, t0.amount, t0.customer_gender, t0.customer_id, t0.customer_name, t0.food_item, t0.phone_number, t0_qt_gjznucnwed, t0.rating, t0.zipCode ORDER BY t0.food_item DESC LIMIT 2000001;

Actually, I tried partitioning and clustering the data and materialized view, also used BI-engine with 3GB capacity but that does not show much improvement in the report's performance.

I am eager to know whether it is possible to load report in this scenario under **5 seconds**.
If YES, how we can we do it?
If NO, is this the expected behavior? Will the performance remain the same with a large data size of **3TB**?

Edit:
I am using this query to join 3 tables:

SELECT
t2.food_item as food_item,
t2.amount as amount,
t1.address as address,
t3.agent_name as agent_name ,
t1.gender as customer_gender,
t1.customer_id as customer_id,
t1.customer_name as customer_name,
t1.date as date,
t3.phone_number as phone_number,
t1.zip_code as zipCode,
t3.rating as rating
FROM
`project_id.my_dataset.customers_data` as t1
JOIN
`project_id.my_dataset.orders_data` as t2
ON
t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
JOIN
`project_id.my_dataset.agents_data` as t3
ON
t2.order_id = t3.order_id

Answer (score 0):

We have been on this road, the solution is dedicated TABLE for datastudio reports, it could be dedicated for chart as well.

1. A scheduler that regularely replaces a dedicated table for DataStudio reports. Eg run every 5m / 15 m / 1h / 24h
2. this is acieved with the syntax of

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE datastudio.table1 AS  
    .....  
    select query1;  
    .....  
    CREATE OR REPLACE ........;
```

we have many of these small tables optimized for datastudio

also you can cluster these table based on the elements that you use as filters, date, dimension1, d2, d3 etc...

3. BI Engine works flaweless as this table is not changing. If you opt for 15min schedule, the cache will invalidate only after that period. Our BI engine is 4GB in size.
4. Disable timetravel on these datasets.
5. Create multiple tables if different clustering needs to be achieved, with the additional tables integration workload.

Comment: Thanks for your approach. I will definitely try this. Meanwhile can you tell if we can schedule a Looker studio query so that the BigQuery cache never expires and the initial report load works fast.

Comment: yes many ways to do here https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7020039?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: It looks like the dedicated table is also taking amount of time to return the response. Also above article also don't address my concern. Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to understand large table vs chart. I assume if you go and create for each chart a reduced table, only with the metrics you need for that char, there is no way to be large. Are you doing this?

Comment: Actually, I found that chart queries with limited number of metrics takes less time but to get an idea of worst case scenario we have created a table with all the dimensions, this query processes around 1.5 GB of data and this is the table that is taking the majority of time. Can we take any steps to minimize its loading time ?